# Get current date data from Content Provider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I have to get data from ContentProvider based on current month. For getting the data, I used following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Festivals
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',fest_date) >= date('now','-6 days') AND
strftime('%Y-%m-%d',fest_date)<=date('now') order by fest_date
```

I tried to write the same in the CursorLoader as follows:

```
new CursorLoader(this, FestivalContract.Festivals.CONTENT_URI, 
            PROJECTION, "strftime('%Y-%m-%d',fest_date)>=? AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',fest_date)<=?", new String[] { "date('now','-6 days')", "date('now')" },
            FestivalContract.Festivals.FestivalColumns.FEST_NAME + " asc");
```

But, it returned all records. I am unable to find what is wrong in my code.

Comment: you passed `fest_date` variable as an string. `"strftime('%Y-%m-%d',fest_date)>=? AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',fest_date)<=?", new String[] { "date('now','-6 days')", "date('now')" }`

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I forgot to mention, fest_date is name of one of the column in my DB table.

Comment: Understood, but any alternative to do this. Because, I don't want to fetch data for the whole year at once as it would be wastage only. I have to highlight those dates on calendar on which there will be any event

Comment: @Downvoter Any reason to downvote?

Comment: Just try to put some value in your query params instead of `new String[] { "date('now','-6 days')", "date('now')" }` to see if it works or not, in this way you can check it your problem is in there or not.

Comment: @Sirlate Ya, I tried that with executing `date()` separately, and passing its output in array. But, again all records are returned. `strftime()` is also not working in cursor loader.

Comment: So a simple workaround would be to just store data in simple unix format in your database and execute your query with to long  number, one that indicates System.currentTime and one that indicates 6 days ago.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please? I didn't understood your point.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probebly you query method in content provider is something like this:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        // check if the caller has requested a column which does not exists
        checkColumns(projection);
        // Set the table
        queryBuilder.setTables(MessageTable.TABLE_NAME);
        int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (uriType) {
            case MESSAGES:
                break;

            case MESSAGE_ID:
                // adding the ID to the original query
                queryBuilder.appendWhere(MessageTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
                break;

            case BROADCAST_MESSAGES:
                groupBy = MessageTable.COLUMN_MESSAGE_ID;
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknow URI: " + uri);
```

And if you are using queryBuilder cannot achieve your goal.
You have two workarounds:

1- Store you date in database in a long format. for example your festival date is unix formated date which means you should store each date as long number in your database. then write you query in cursorloader like this:

```
new CursorLoader(this, FestivalContract.Festivals.CONTENT_URI, 
        PROJECTION, "fest_date>=? AND fest_date<=?", new String[] { System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis() - 6 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)", "" },
        FestivalContract.Festivals.FestivalColumns.FEST_NAME + " asc");
```

2- The second solution is to customize your `ContentProvider` and add a different `Content_Uri` for this special query that you want to make, and then in `query` method of your provider check if you are querying this special uri, then instead of using `QueryBuilder` which does not let you run sql method, just execute your query string on database object that you have in content provider, something like this:

```
return database.rawQuery(your_query_string_with_sql_methods, new String['your_params_or_whatever]);
```

Comment: By the way, I prefer the first approach.

Comment: Yes, I did. Still the cursor is returning all records. Can't understand why.

Comment: Even without using `strftime` method?!

Comment: Yes, this time I had converted date to long.

Comment: So, you should double check your code, I guess you have made a simple mistake some where.

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault, I wrote wrong query. Just checked it on Sqlite Browser.:)

Answer (score 0):

Parameters (`?`) are used for string that you do not want to be executed.

But you want to execute the `date` functions. Just put them directly into the SQL query.

Comment: But, Content Provider does not supports `rawQuery`. So, how can I accomplish this? Do you mean to say, to execute date function separately and pass their output as selection args?

Comment: No, replace the character `?` with `date(...)`. (`date` is a function like `strftime`.)

Comment: Tried already, but due to `strftime()`, it didn't gave desired output.  Eventhough, I execute strftime() in a separate query, I am not getting how do I pass that output in the projection. I need to format the date as server sent date and time together.

Comment: Does the first query in your question actually work?

Comment: Yes, that in sqlite syntax.

Comment: Then the `CursorLoader` call with *exactly* the same WHERE clause should work, too.

Comment: That's what I expected. But, didn't got the result. Probably, the sqlite functions are not executed. Sorry, I am not too good in database. So I may be wrong. To test it, executed date() separately. I can pass the output date() in selection args. But, what about strftime()> That's what I am not getting, It will return around 50 records in the cursor which needs to passed as selection.

Comment: `date` and `strftime` work the same in any version of SQLite. Your problem appears to be a different database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59639/discussion-between-nitish-and-cl).